# how to broadcast rf on an iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, wifi

I am just wondering how would i come about if i want to turn my cell phone into a standalone cell tower that emits rf around it. Is there a function in the SDK available for me? It would be similar to the tethering app which creates wifi spots from an iphone.

Regards

Answer (score 4):

No.

Cellular standards such as GSM (2G) and UMTS (3G) are highly asymmetrical; the hardware for a downlink receiver can't easily be converted into an uplink receiver, for instance.

Wi-Fi essentially has a symmetrical physical layer (there is no real concept of "uplink" and "downlink").

Comment: hi does that mean making a wifi hot spot out of an iphone is doable while making a cell tower out of an iphone is not?